# Ubuntu One hangs at the end of installation

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one

I've just upgrade to ubuntu 11.10 and pressed to install ubuntu one from settings. The procedure started but stopped at the very end and hangs.

Tried uninstalling and reinstalling but no change.

Please can you suggest a solution or is this a bug.
I like to use my cloud as a backup.

Comment: is der any background installation goin on like synaptic or Ubuntu software center?

also ubuntu one is installed by default...
you may be asking of having it integrated with nautilus

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu One install screen does not finish](http://askubuntu.com/questions/103252/ubuntu-one-install-screen-does-not-finish)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk
```

Comment: Did your suggestion and pressed the U1 in settings and everything was fine. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If `sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk` doesn't work, then go into Synaptic (`sudo apt-get install synaptic`), remove everything to do with `ubuntuone` and then reinstall everything.  The installer seems to hang because for whatever reason it needs `ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk` installed, but doesn't actually install.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had to uninstall all ubuntuone stuff from the Muon Software Center then using the Muon Package Manager, searched on unbuntuone, selected everything that was not for debugging and installed. After, I went to "Settings", and found a "Ubuntu One" option. I selected it and it ran the installer.

wmrobins