# Ubuntu One install screen does not finish

Tags: 11.10, installation, ubuntu-one, backup

This is an issue that Ive had around for a long time, and havent been able to solve. Please help me out guys, I really need Ubuntu One to run on my computer.

I run Ubuntu 2D, On Ubuntu 11.10. When I start Ubuntu One, the install screen comes and asks me if I want to install Ubuntu One. I install it, type in my password and all of that, but the bar never finishes loading! It goes to the end and then nothing happens.

At first I thought it had to do with the fact that I had Déjà Dup Backup, So I removed both and installed Ubuntu One again through the software center. Same problem.

Please help!

Comment: Ubuntu One is preinstalled, are you sure you are installing it again? A screenshot might help people understand your question better, too. Try following [this tutorial](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/tutorial/install-and-setup-ubuntu-one/) and give us the exact step you have problems at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu One installer won't finish the process if the ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk is not installed.

So, install the related packages and you can use Ubuntu One thereafter.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-client-gnome ubuntuone-control-panel ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk
```

([Related bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntuone-installer/+bug/853060))

Comment: This is a known bug and in the process of being fixed. The solution posted above using apt-get should work.

Comment: I've same problem on precise using amd64

Comment: @ale Try installing `ubuntuone-control-panel-qt`.

Comment: @jokerdino I did that, worked wonderfully, thanks.