# One file not syncing

Tags: ubuntu-one, indicator, sync

I put 3 files in the UbuntuOne folder. The 2 smaller ones (few kilos) synced no problem.
The 3rd one (600Megs) hasn't, and it's been there a couple of days now. It shows the syncing icon when browsing, but the app tells me that no files are currently syncing.

Any idea what I can do to "force" or restart the syning? Or how to get something like an indicator by file being synced?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here `~/.cache/ubuntuone/log` in the log files. Maybe you find some hint there what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu 11.10 32 bit system the files stopped syncing.

I followed these instructions to completely remove and reinstall:  https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/how-do-i-completely-remove-and-reinstall-ubuntu-one/

When the reinstall hung, I followed these instructions:  [Ubuntu One hangs at the end of installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71844/ubuntu-one-hangs-at-the-end-of-installation)

I then checked the status with u1sdtool --status according to this page:  http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/u1sdtool.1.html

Works now.  Shouldn't be this difficult.